# How can I target a specific AppWidgetProvider with an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I implemented a widget for my tasks application, and I would like its `AppWidgetProvider` to receive custom data-changed notification broadcasts. Because I would like to target these broadcasts to registered components within my app, the `WidgetProvider` instance being one of them, I'm using `Intent`'s setComponent() API. The `widgetProvider` is only receiving the intent when I remove the call to `setComponent()` and if I add the intent filter to the `WidgetProvider` component in the AndroidManifest.xml. How can I get `setComponent()` to work? Below is a representation of the code I'm working with.

```
package com.mypackage.widgets;

public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static {
        MyActivity.registerChangeListener( new ComponentName( 
            WidgetProvider.class.getPackage().getName(), WidgetProvider.class.getName() ) );
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context ctx, Intent intent ) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if( MyActivity.FETCH_DATA_ACTION.equals( action ) ) {
            // This only runs when I *don't* call setComponent() on the intent
            ...
            // fetch data
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

...

```
package com.mypackage;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String FETCH_DATA_ACTION = "com.mypackage.MyActivity.FETCH_DATA";

    private static ArrayList<ComponentName> sChangeListeners = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();

    public static void registerChangeListener( ComponentName cn ) {
        sChangeListeners.add( cn );
    }

    private static void notifyChangeListeners() {
        for( ComponentName cn: sChangeListeners ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction( FETCH_DATA_ACTION );
            intent.setComponent( cn );
            sendBroadcast( intent );
        }
    }

    ...
        changeData();
        notifyChangeListeners();
    ...
}
```

WidgetProvider is registered in my AndroidManifest as follows:

```
<receiver android:name=".widgets.WidgetProvider"
    android:exported="false">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComponentName` instances are built with Android package names, not java package names.  If `WidgetProvider.class.getPackage().getName()` does not equal the name of your package as specified in `AndroidManifest.xml`, calling `setComponent(cn)` will point to an invalid component.

Comment: What do you mean by Android package name as opposed to Java package name?

Comment: Android package name = [package](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package) attribute in your `<manifest>`.  The java package name is the package name of your `WidgetProvider` java class, which may be a subpackage.  You should not use java package names when constructing ComponentNames.

Comment: I try that but it doesn't work either: new ComponentName( "com.mypackage", "WidgetProvider" )

Comment: The class name is the fully qualified java class name.  What you had before should be fine for the class name part of the component name.

Comment: Eureka, that worked. Thanks @jspurlock. The documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#ComponentName(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) needs to be more clear in that it should specify app package name as opposed to java package name.